# Image not displaying - Symfony twig

Tags: php, symfony

I am fairly new to Symfony and trying to figure out how to display an image from a database. I followed the Symfony documentation and when I inspect it shows me the right path however I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Controller code :

```
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $repa = new Repas();
    $form = $this->createForm(RepasType::class, $repa);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $img = $request->files->get('repas')['img'];
        $uploads_directory = $this->getParameter('uploads_directory');

        $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $img->guessExtension();
        $img->move(
            $uploads_directory,
            $filename

        );
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $repa->setimg($filename);


       $entityManager->persist($repa);
      $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('repas_index');
    }

    return $this->render('repas/new.html.twig', [
        'repa' => $repa,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Twig code :

`{% for repa in repas %} <img src="{{ asset('public/uploads/' ~ repa.getImg()) }}" alt="img" class="cover-image">`

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and thank you in advance x

Comment: Hey, just a blank space, nothing shows, what gets me is that when I inspect elements, I get the full path and the image name. (src="/public/uploads/e9cd9b708af1d706add7e529332fc665.png")

Comment: And have you checked that this file exists? If you copy that path, put it after your host and access via browser, do you see the image?

Comment: Yes it does appear

Comment: try to remove "public/" from path, because asset means folder public

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
{{ asset('uploads/' ~ repa.getImg()) }}
```

All your requests are redirect to the `public` folder, so it's not necessary to add `public/` to the asset.

Comment: Thank you very much :) that was the issue x